# Cannot resolve symbol 'MobileElement', 'AndroidElement', and 'IOSElement' in Appium Java-client 8.0.0Beta. How to resolve this?

Tags: selenium, appium

MobileElement, AndroidElement, and IOSElement are not available in Appium Java-client 8.0.0Beta when migrate from Appium Java-Client 7.6.0

Comment: I go the answer for this. https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/v7-to-v8-migration-guide.md#mobileelement

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I was using Appium Java-Client 8.1.1 I had to downgrade it back to Appium Java-Client 7.6.0. After the downgrade it worked

Comment: Downgrading helped me, thanks